# Mac Installing Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I used brew to installed the mongoDB. Created the database and permission.

```
Suns-MacBook-Pro:~ Dawn$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
Suns-MacBook-Pro:~ Dawn$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test
```

It keeps connecting after 5 minutes. Any suggestions what problem here

Comment: What do you mean by "It keeps connecting after 5 minutes"?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the --dbpath to set the data directory.
Example: mongod --dbpath /var/mongodata
/var/mongodata should be created first.

Comment: The content of /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log would help.